# Getting class object from an iOS bundle for a nested class or in an extension

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, bundle

Using Bundle.main.classNamed works fine given the app name and a class name that's at the root level, so for the following setup in an app called MyApp, for example:

```
class Foo {
  class Bar {}
}

extension Foo {
  class Baz { }
}
```

I have success getting Foo's class object using `Bundle.main.classNamed("MyApp.Foo")`

I want to get Bar and Baz's class Object in the same manner.

Intuitively, I've tried `Bundle.main.classNamed("MyApp.Foo.Bar")` and `Bundle.main.classNamed("MyApp.Foo.Baz")` but both of these return nil.

Is there another type of separator I need to use? Is it possible to get the object of a nested class from the bundle at all?